# Delete the first four letters of all the values in a dictionary

Tags: python

If you had a dictionary like this:

```
a = {}
a['first']='123456'
a['second']='123456'
a['third']='123456'
```

It would look like this:

```
{'third': '123456', 'first': '123456', 'second': '123456'}
```

Is there an efficient way to change it to this?:

```
{'third': '56', 'first': '56', 'second': '56'}
```

Comment: `dict.fromkeys(a, '56')`?

Comment: Do you need to modify the dictionary in place, or create a new dictionary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using string slicing and a dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> a = {}
>>> a['first']='123456'
>>> a['second']='123456'
>>> a['third']='123456'
>>> a = {k: v[4:] for k, v in a.items()}
>>> a
{'first': '56', 'second': '56', 'third': '56'}
```

For in place changes:

```
for k, v in a.items():
    a[k] = v[4:]
```

Comment: Or, just use `v[-2:]` to support input with values of arbitrary length.

Comment: @Ajax1234 That would take the last 2 values, not remove the first 4, which I believe is what is desired.

Comment: Reasonable answer, although I wonder if he needs to modify the dictionary in place.

Comment: @Barmar Good point, if this is for an assignment it's definitely a possibility.